# Multiple file extensions in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

How can I use multiple file extensions within one group using `OpenFileDialog`?
I have `Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tiff"`
and I want to create groups so JPG are *.jpg and *.jpeg, TIFF are *.tif and *.tiff and also 'All graphic types'? How can I do that?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

[Try](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx):

```
Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff"
```

Then do another round of copy/paste of all the extensions (joined together with `;` as above) for "All graphics types":

```
Filter = "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
       + "All Graphics Types|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff"
```

Comment: I would suggest putting the "ALL" option first, as that what seems to be the default.

Comment: Don't put a `|` in the description part, it will miss-parse it.

Answer (score 82):

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) sample:

```
(*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg
```

So for your case

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG (*.jpg,*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|TIFF (*.tif,*.tiff)|*.tif;*.tiff"
```

Comment: This solution is more elegant, correct and desired. This should be the most up-voted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on First answer here is the complete image selection options:

```
Filter = @"|All Image Files|*.BMP;*.bmp;*.JPG;*.JPEG*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.PNG;*.png;*.GIF;*.gif;*.tif;*.tiff;*.ico;*.ICO
           |PNG|*.PNG;*.png
           |JPEG|*.JPG;*.JPEG*.jpg;*.jpeg
           |Bitmap(.BMP,.bmp)|*.BMP;*.bmp                                    
           |GIF|*.GIF;*.gif
           |TIF|*.tif;*.tiff
           |ICO|*.ico;*.ICO";
```

Comment: You don't want the leading separator. It is "All Image Files|*.BMP..." rather than "|All Image Files|*.BMP...".